# How to move a function to reducers (redux-toolkit)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

**I have a function that makes a request and returns data - *Main.tsx*:**

```
async function fetchProducts(productsPage = 1, id?: number) {
    const itemsPerPage = 5

    let url: string
    if (id) {
        url = `https://reqres.in/api/products/${id}`
    } else {
        url = `https://reqres.in/api/products?per_page=${itemsPerPage}&page=${productsPage}`
    }
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(async (response) => {
            const data = await response.json()

            if (response.ok) {
                if (id) {
                    console.log(products)
                    dispatch(
                        getProducts({
                            page: 1,
                            per_page: 1,
                            total: 1,
                            total_pages: 1,
                            data: [data.data],
                        })
                    )
                    console.log(products)
                } else {
                    dispatch(getProducts(data))
                }
            } else {
                const error = (data && data.message) || response.status
                return Promise.reject(error)
            }
            setErrorId(data.id)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setErrorMessage(error.toString())
            console.error('There was an error!', error)
        })
}
```

**I also have a storage where I can store this data - *storage.ts* :**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { IProducts } from '../components/Products/products.interface'

type ProductsState = {
    list: IProducts
}

const initialState: ProductsState = {
    list: {
        data: [{ id: 0, name: '', year: 0, color: '', pantone_value: '' }],
        page: 0,
        per_page: 0,
        total: 0,
        total_pages: 0,
    },
}

const ProductsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'getProducts',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getProducts(state, action: PayloadAction<IProducts>) {
            return { list: action.payload }
        },
    },
})

export const { getProducts } = ProductsSlice.actions

export default ProductsSlice.reducer
```

The store currently only has an accept data action. And the main function for getting this data is in the .tsx file.

***I understand that it would be more correct if my function is in reducers, but I don’t know how to transfer it there.***

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent opportunity to use thunks with `createAsyncThunk`

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

```
// abstract your fetch function wherever you want, maybe in a utils folder such as lib/products.ts
async function fetchProducts(productsPage = 1, id?: number) {
    const itemsPerPage = 5

    let url: string
    if (id) {
        url = `https://reqres.in/api/products/${id}`
    } else {
        url = `https://reqres.in/api/products?per_page=${itemsPerPage}&page=${productsPage}`
    }
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }

    return fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(async (response) => {
            return await response.json()
        }
    )
}


// in your actions file
// eg. if your reducer is called in store/products/slice/productsSlice.ts then your action file should be store/products/actions/productsActions.ts
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
    'products/fetchProducts',
    async ({ id, productsPage }, _thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const data = await fetchProducts(productsPage, id);
            return {
                data,
                page: 1,
                per_page: 1,
                total: 1,
                total_pages: 1,
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return error
        }
    }
)

// in your component

const handleGetProducts = async (id?: number, productsPage?: number) => {
    const res = await dispatch(fetchProducts({ id, productsPage }))
    .unwrap()
    .then((res) => {
        // do something inside your component after the promise is resolved
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        setErrorMessage(err.toString())
        console.error('There was an error!', err)
    })
}

// your slice file
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { IProducts } from '../components/Products/products.interface'
import { fetchProducts } from '../actions/productsActions'

type ProductsState = {
    list: IProducts
}

const initialState: ProductsState = {
    list: {
        data: [{ id: 0, name: '', year: 0, color: '', pantone_value: '' }],
        page: 0,
        per_page: 0,
        total: 0,
        total_pages: 0,
    },
    error: undefined,
    loading: false,
}

const ProductsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'products',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.list = action.payload
            state.loading = false
        }),
        builder.addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.error = action.error.message // or some error you want to store
        }),
        builder.addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true
        })
    }
})
```